# Trouble Scraping a Responsive Bootstrap Table

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a table off of https://www.pepperscale.com/hot-pepper-list/ that is proving to be a problem. When I call the website either through `requests` or `urllib` I'm only getting the first 10 results of the table, even though by default I usually see all the rows.

The issue is, since it's a bootstrap table, the pages don't show in the URL. Has anyone been able to crack these tables? My codes are below:

**Using URLLib:**

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36'}
reg_url = "https://www.pepperscale.com/hot-pepper-list/"
req = Request(url=reg_url, headers=headers) 
html = urlopen(req).read()

pepscrap = pd.read_html(html)
print(pepscrap[0])
```

**Using BS4 (didn't finish because I saw only 10 rows)**

```
page = requests.get("https://www.pepperscale.com/hot-pepper-list/", verify=False)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup.find(id='table_1'))
```

Comment: The rest of the table is loaded in via js. If you use something like selenium you can wait for that and then do the scrape.

Answer (score 3):

You're probably better off just talking with the same API which populates the bootstrap table in the first place. I used Google Chrome's network logger to view only XHR (`XmlHttpRequest`) resources that my browser made requests to. By inspecting the contents of the filtered resources I determined that the browser makes a request to their API using this URL: https://www.pepperscale.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=get_wdtable&table_id=5

For whatever reason, you need to make a POST- rather than a GET-request - every API is different, whatever. In the "Header and request body" tab you can see the form parameters that the API expects - these seem to be important. I haven't tried to figure out which are critical and which are not required, so I just constructed my POST-request with the same form parameters that my browser sent.

This yields a nice JSON response, which is trivial to parse:

```
import requests

url = "https://www.pepperscale.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=get_wdtable&table_id=5"

data = {
    "draw": "1",
    "columns[0][data]": "0",
    "columns[0][name]": "wdt_ID",
    "columns[0][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[0][orderable]": "true",
    "columns[0][search][value]": "",
    "columns[0][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[1][data]": "1",
    "columns[1][name]": "heat",
    "columns[1][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[1][orderable]": "true",
    "columns[1][search][value]": "",
    "columns[1][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[2][data]": "2",
    "columns[2][name]": "image",
    "columns[2][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[2][orderable]": "false",
    "columns[2][search][value]": "",
    "columns[2][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[3][data]": "3",
    "columns[3][name]": "hotpepper",
    "columns[3][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[3][orderable]": "true",
    "columns[3][search][value]": "",
    "columns[3][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[4][data]": "4",
    "columns[4][name]": "minshu",
    "columns[4][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[4][orderable]": "true",
    "columns[4][search][value]": "",
    "columns[4][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[5][data]": "5",
    "columns[5][name]": "maxshu",
    "columns[5][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[5][orderable]": "false",
    "columns[5][search][value]": "",
    "columns[5][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[6][data]": "6",
    "columns[6][name]": "formula_1",
    "columns[6][searchable]": "false",
    "columns[6][orderable]": "false",
    "columns[6][search][value]": "",
    "columns[6][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[7][data]": "7",
    "columns[7][name]": "formula_2",
    "columns[7][searchable]": "false",
    "columns[7][orderable]": "false",
    "columns[7][search][value]": "",
    "columns[7][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[8][data]": "8",
    "columns[8][name]": "jalrp",
    "columns[8][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[8][orderable]": "false",
    "columns[8][search][value]": "",
    "columns[8][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[9][data]": "9",
    "columns[9][name]": "type",
    "columns[9][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[9][orderable]": "true",
    "columns[9][search][value]": "",
    "columns[9][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[10][data]": "10",
    "columns[10][name]": "origin",
    "columns[10][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[10][orderable]": "false",
    "columns[10][search][value]": "",
    "columns[10][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[11][data]": "11",
    "columns[11][name]": "use",
    "columns[11][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[11][orderable]": "false",
    "columns[11][search][value]": "",
    "columns[11][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[12][data]": "12",
    "columns[12][name]": "flavor",
    "columns[12][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[12][orderable]": "false",
    "columns[12][search][value]": "",
    "columns[12][search][regex]": "false",
    "order[0][column]": "5",
    "order[0][dir]": "asc",
    "start": "0",
    "length": "-1",
    "search[value]": "",
    "search[regex]": "false",
    "wdtNonce": "2f82d8936d"
}

response = requests.post(url, data=data)
response.raise_for_status()

peppers = response.json()["data"]

# print out the first pepper information
print(peppers[0])
```

Output:

```
['1', 'Mild', "<a href='https://www.pepperscale.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Tasty-Colorbell-Pepper-4-Plants-GreenYellowPurpleRed-0.jpg' target='_blank' rel='lightbox[-1]'><img src='https://www.pepperscale.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Tasty-Colorbell-Pepper-4-Plants-GreenYellowPurpleRed-0-75x75.jpg' /></a>", "<a data-content='Bell Pepper' href='https://www.pepperscale.com/bell-pepper' target='_blank'>Bell Pepper</a>", '0', '0', '0', '0.00', '-8,000 to -2,500', 'annuum', 'Mexico', 'Culinary', 'Bright, Sweet']
```